# Is It Possible To Do An 80's Style Anime Shading? If So How?

Tags: texturing, materials, compositing-nodes, shaders, lighting

I'm familiar with a lot of the basics of how to model, texture, apply materials, use nodes, basic rigging & animating, etc.

I ran across a YouTube video called "TIE Fighter - short film" from a user named "OtaKing77077" and fell in LOVE with the art style as it reminded SO much of the Transformers: The Movie from the 80's. For reference here's a screen shot from the YouTube TIE Fighter video:
[image]

So I'm mainly looking for IF this is doable and if so, how would I go about doing it? I'm not AS concerned with the models themselves (unless that is somehow tied to the shading effect), mostly in this type of SHADING.

Another frame of reference would be the recent Transformers: Devastation which is I suppose an obvious answer that this is doable in 3D because it's a 3D game, but I wasn't sure if it was doable in a 3D modeling environment, outside of a game engine with GPU shaders and code and such like what they did for the game:
[image]

Another note would be I've used both Blender Render & Cycles and prefer Cycles but if this is somehow easier to achieve or of a higher quality in the internal renderer I have no problem using either.

I would appreciate ANY help anyone may have on this topic, and thanks in advance to anyone who responds.

Comment: I think it would be helpful if you try to list what are in your opinion the "key features" of the shader/shaders.

Comment: I'm not really sure exactly. Not being an artist I'm not entirely sure how to describe it. I suppose the "key features" would be that everything looks "glossier" than typical cel shading which gives it a more detailed look? But I didn't think if I used a "standard" cel shaded look and just cranked the specularity up that it would create the detailed look it would just make it brighter, right? Cause there seems to be a LOT of different reflections not just like a large area that's shaded but it's a lot of little strands of reflection. Hope that makes sense lol. :P

Comment: The shaders aren't what's giving it this look. It's the art style and textures.

Comment: @Brayden Oh, really? Cause when you actually play the game the reflections and everything moves around, it seemed too dynamic to be from the textures.

I mean I understand the TIE Fighter reference cause that I think was done by a 2D artist in photoshop so that I get. But I didn't think the Transformer one could be done with just textures. o.O

Comment: It's a blend of both. Watch Optimus's legs closely here: https://youtu.be/EHcBxPJPx10?t=7m25s

Comment: @Brayden Oh I see, you mean how the lighting isn't "really" moving even though the object is so that part must be some form of texture work. Interesting...

Comment: Yep, Nathan's answer is correct. The rest is done with the artstyle and texturing. Get some comic-booky textures and then tweak the cel shading and you should be able to achieve something similar eventually.

Comment: Please keep questions short and to the point. As it currently stands this is far too broad to be reasonably answerable here. You might want to take a look into [Blender Freestyle rendering](https://www.google.com/search?q=blender+freestyle&tbm=vid). It can help in producing non photorealistic renderings and cell-shading-like effects. Blender internal may also be more adequate, although not mandatory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This technique is known as Cel-shading. There are quite a few tutorials on how to handle Cel-shading in Blender; I'd recommend starting here to get a reference on how to get the basics down.
[Toon Shading in Cycles](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d08WF6sZuQI)

Comment: Well I know about cel shading. I've actually tried a few different tutorials in blender that look "good" in that it looks like a "typical" toon shading. But the look in the two references is more detailed somehow. Like there's more detailed reflections and more of them or something that seemed specific to the 80's anime art style. So I was looking more for a way to do that particular form of cel shading.